# How to show that $(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}x)^{-1} = \sigma^2 + x^TA^{-1}x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I want to show that
$$\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1} = \sigma^2 + x^TA^{-1}x$$
where $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

The following python program indicates that it is true because the difference between the left- and the right-hand side is always relatively small ($< 10^{-4}$). However, I don't know how to proceed.

To speak informally, I think I need to somehow move the inverse from $(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}$ to the $A$ because then everything falls into place but I don't see how.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *

# Sample matrices and data
d = 10
sigma2 = np.random.rand() + 0.0001
A = np.random.randn(d, d)
x = (np.random.rand(d) - 0.5) * 1000

# Ensure invertibility
assert det(A) != 0.0

left = 1/(1 / (x @ x) * x.T @ A @ inv(sigma2 * A + np.outer(x, x)) @ x)
right = sigma2 + x.T @ inv(A) @ x

abs(left - right)
# usually on the order of 10^-5 because of instability in the matrix
# inversion I guess
```

Comment: I just asked a very similar, ill-formed question which I have now deleted and replaced it with this more open formulation and some evidence.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple calculation showing that both $B^{-1}B=I$ and $BB^{-1}=I$ do it.

Comment: I tried that in the afternoon and could not finish it because there is still the sum in the inverse on the left-hand side which I did not know how to deal with.

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be symmetric and positive-definite?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will put it in the question text.

Comment: Where you wrote $\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1},$ I wonder if you might have meant $\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1} Ax \right)^{-1}. \qquad$

Comment: An possible alternative approach: it might be helpful to note that
$$
x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}x = \\
x^TA((\sigma^2I + xx^TA^{-1})A)^{-1}x = \\
x^TAA^{-1}(\sigma^2I + xx^TA^{-1})^{-1}x = \\
x^T(\sigma^2I + xx^TA^{-1})^{-1}x
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Sherman Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), we have
$$
\begin{align}
(\sigma^2 A + xx^T)^{-1} &= \sigma^{-2} A^{-1} - \sigma^{-4}\frac {A^{-1}xx^T A^{-1}}{1 + \sigma^{-2} x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}
\\ & = 
\sigma^{-2} A^{-1} - \sigma^{-2}\frac {A^{-1}xx^T A^{-1}}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}
\\ & = 
\sigma^{-2} \left[A^{-1} - \frac {A^{-1}xx^T A^{-1}}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}\right].
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
x^TA(\sigma^2 A + xx^T)^{-1}x &= \sigma^{-2} x^TA\left[A^{-1} - \frac {A^{-1}xx^T A^{-1}}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}\right]x
\\ & = \sigma^{-2} x^TAA^{-1}x - \sigma^{-2}x^TA\frac {A^{-1}xx^T A^{-1}}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}x
\\ & = \sigma^{-2} x^Tx - \sigma^{-2}\frac {x^Tx}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}x^T A^{-1}x
\\ & =
\sigma^{-2} x^Tx - \sigma^{-2}\frac {x^Tx}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}[\sigma^2 + x^T A^{-1}x] + 
\frac {x^Tx}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}
\\ & = 
\sigma^{-2} x^Tx - \sigma^{-2}{x^Tx} + 
\frac {x^Tx}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x} 
\\ & = \frac {x^Tx}{\sigma^2 +  x^\textsf{T}A^{-1}x}.
\end{align}
$$
Your observation follows.

Comment: I suspect that a more elegant proof could be made using block-matrices

Answer (score 2):

An intuitive way to understand the identity is to expand $A(\sigma^2A+xx^T)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left(I+\frac{xx^TA^{-1}}{\sigma^2}\right)^{-1}$ as a power series in $\frac{xx^TA^{-1}}{\sigma^2}$. Unfortunately, the series does not always converge. But the idea can be salvaged. Let $B=\frac{xx^TA^{-1}}{\sigma^2}$. Then $B$ has rank one. Hence its trace
$$
\lambda=\frac{x^TA^{-1}x}{\sigma^2}
$$
is an eigenvalue. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, there is a polynomial $p$ such that
$$
p(B)=(I+B)^{-1};\ \text{ hence }\ p(\lambda)=(1+\lambda)^{-1}.
$$
Now, for every integer $k\ge0$, we have
$$
x^TB^kx
=x^T\left(\frac{xx^TA^{-1}}{\sigma^2}\right)^kx
=x^Tx\left(\frac{x^TA^{-1}x}{\sigma^2}\right)^k
=\lambda^kx^Tx.
$$
Therefore $x^Tp(B)x=p(\lambda)\,x^Tx$, i.e.
$$
x^T(I+B)^{-1}x=(1+\lambda)^{-1}x^Tx.
$$
It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx}x^TA(\sigma^2A+xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2x^Tx}x^T(I+B)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}
=\sigma^2(1+\lambda)
=\sigma^2+x^TA^{-1}x.
\end{aligned}

---

**Update.** As Omnomnomnom suspected, the identity arises naturally from manipulations of block matrices, but we need to rewrite the identity first. Let $A_0=\sigma^2A$. Then
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx}x^TA(\sigma^2A+xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}=\sigma^2+x^TA^{-1}x\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx}x^TA_0(A_0+xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}=1+x^TA_0^{-1}x\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx}x^T\left((A_0+xx^T)-xx^T\right)(A_0+xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}=1+x^TA_0^{-1}x\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left(1-x^T(A_0+xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}=1+x^TA_0^{-1}x\\
&\Leftrightarrow1-x^T(A_0+xx^T)^{-1}x=\left(1+x^TA_0^{-1}x\right)^{-1}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
How last identity arises is now evident: it originates from [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) identity, which arises from writing the inverse of a block matrix in two equivalent ways:
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}^{-1}
=\pmatrix{(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}
=\pmatrix{A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}
$$
The identity $(1)$ is just the case when
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}=\pmatrix{1&-x^T\\ x&A_0}.
$$

Comment: I find this much more satisfying than my answer. Thanks for writing this up

Answer (score 0):

From user1551's second proof using the Schur complement identity I learned about the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) (or Sherman–Morrison–Woodbury formula)
$$(A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}.$$
This shows the identity in an even more direct way when $A := \sigma^2A$, $U := x$, $C := I$ and $V := x^T$ (though it is essentially the same computation as given by Omnomnomnom).

$$
\begin{align}
& \left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^2A + xx^T)^{-1}x\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TA(\sigma^{-2}A^{-1} - \sigma^{-4}A^{-1}x(I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}x^T A^{-1})x\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \sigma^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^Tx} x^TAA^{-1}x - \frac{\sigma^{-2}}{x^Tx} x^TAA^{-1}x(I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}x^T A^{-1}x\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \sigma^{2}\left(1 - (I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}\sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \sigma^{2}\left(1 - (I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}((I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x) - I)\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \sigma^{2}\left(1 - (I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}(I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x) + (I + \sigma^{-2}x^T A^{-1}x)^{-1}\right)^{-1}\\
= &\, \sigma^{2} + x^T A^{-1} x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that the term $(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U)^{-1}$ when you apply Woodbury matrix is in fact a $1 \times 1$ matrix, i.e. a scalar.  Because of this, applying the Woodbury identity to your case gives you the Sherman Morrison formula, which is what I used. If you follow our posts closely, you should find that your approach and mine are almost identical.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much. I would have never figured this out.